# iPhone 1 gen , slide to unlock is not responding

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 1 gen and the iOS version 3.1.1 the latest for 1st gen iPhone. Suddenly I am not able to slide the slider which unlocks the home screen.

Answer (score 3):

Your phone has likely hung. Press and hold the power button to try to power it off. If that still fails to happen, the other solution would be to **hard reset** the iphone:

To reset the iPhone, simply press the POWER/SLEEP button and Home button together. Hold them until you can see the boot screen, which is with black background and Apple logo. One point to note is you have to release both buttons at the same time.

This will not erase your data.

If the iPhone fails to work after that, you might have to restore it using iTunes. But I don’t think that’s the case.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 already done no response ...i think i have to go for step 3 a restore

Comment: If you press and hold both HOME and POWER at the same time for about 10 seconds and nothing happens, you definitely have a problem. The hardware itself will HARD reset (i.e. cut the power to the board) when that is pressed, independently of the software’s status.

Comment: all the 3 steps failed slide to unlock is not responding

Comment: @paranjai then your only bet is to wait until the battery dries out, only then, you can re-charge it and restart it.